# How to prevent reloading of data in fragments when switching to next or previous

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to stop reloading of recycler view data in fragments when having bottom navigation same like YouTube app. It does not reload view or data on back press or when switching to other tabs.

Comment: Post some code?

Comment: If you are [saving your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) properly and caching your data in a `ViewModel`, then you shouldn't be doing any reloading at all.

Comment: Thanks can you please share some code or senerio how to save the state and caching data.